# Jquery animate() opacity working but animating right does not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

Hi i am trying to animate to the right but it doesn't seem to be working but opacity change does work in the same function?

```
$(document).on("click touchstart tap", ".buttonchat", function () {
   
$('.message').each(function(i) {
   delay =(i)*500;
   
     $(this).delay(delay).animate({
    opacity: 0,
   right: "-150px"

  },1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
   
   
 });
 });
```

as you can see in this pen animating to the right does nothing but changing opacity works what's happening?
pen: https://codepen.io/uiunicorn/pen/YzZXwJp

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS file you should consider adding "." in the beginning.
and Js file here below with corrections.

```js
 $(document).on("click touchstart tap", ".buttonchat", function () {
   
   
   
   $('.message').each(function(i) {
   delay =(i)*500;
   
     $(this).delay(delay).animate({
    "opacity": 0.20 ,
   "right": "0px" , "top": "0px" ,  "background-color" : "green"  

  },1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
 
  });
   
   
 });
 });
```

```css
.message{
  left: 0px;
position : absolute ; 
  }
  
.relative{ position : relative ;   }
```

```html
<button style="width: 200px; height: 100px" class="buttonchat"></button>

<div class="message-main relative">
  <div class="message-hold">
    <div class="messages">
      <div
        class="bubble cornered left"
        style="
          opacity: 1;
          width: 19.2105rem;
          height: 2.47368rem;
          margin-top: 0px;
          margin-left: 0px;
          transform: scale(1);
        "
      >
        <div class="loading" style="transform: translateX(0rem) scale(1)"
          ><b style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0)">•</b
          ><b style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0)">•</b
          ><b style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0)">•</b></div
        ><div
          class="message"
          style="width: 18.2105rem; height: 1.26316rem; opacity: 1"
          >Hello!  I hope you're having a good night</div
        >
      </div>
      <br />
      <div
        class="bubble cornered left"
        style="
          opacity: 1;
          width: 15.7368rem;
          height: 2.47368rem;
          margin-top: 0px;
          margin-left: 0px;
          transform: scale(1);
        "
      >
        <div class="loading" style="transform: translateX(0rem) scale(1)"
          ><b style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0)">•</b
          ><b style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0)">•</b
          ><b style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0)">•</b></div
        ><div
          class="message"
          style="width: 14.7368rem; height: 1.26316rem; opacity: 1"
          >I'm a junior interactive designer </div
        >
      </div>
      <br />
      <div
        class="bubble cornered left"
        style="
          opacity: 1;
          width: 23.8947rem;
          height: 2.47368rem;
          margin-top: 0px;
          margin-left: 0px;
          transform: scale(1);
        "
      >
        <div class="loading" style="transform: translateX(0rem) scale(1)"
          ><b style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0)">•</b
          ><b style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0)">•</b
          ><b style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0)">•</b></div
        >
        <div
          class="message"
          style="width: 22.8421rem; height: 1.26316rem; opacity: 1"
        >
          which basically means I create cool looking websites 
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div
        class="bubble cornered left"
        style="
          opacity: 1;
          width: 30.9474rem;
          height: 2.47368rem;
          margin-top: 0px;
          margin-left: 0px;
          transform: scale(1);
        "
      >
        <div class="loading" style="transform: translateX(0rem) scale(1)"
          ><b style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0)">•</b
          ><b style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0)">•</b
          ><b style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0)">•</b></div
        ><div
          class="message"
          style="width: 29.9474rem; height: 1.26316rem; opacity: 1"
          >I have exactly 0 qualifications and mostly get by using stackoverflow
          </div
        >
      </div>
      <br />
      <div
        class="bubble cornered left"
        style="
          opacity: 1;
          width: 20.3158rem;
          height: 2.47368rem;
          margin-top: 0px;
          margin-left: 0px;
          transform: scale(1);
        "
      >
        <div class="loading" style="transform: translateX(0rem) scale(1)"
          ><b style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0)">•</b
          ><b style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0)">•</b
          ><b style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0)">•</b></div
        ><div
          class="message"
          style="width: 19.3158rem; height: 1.26316rem; opacity: 1"
          >Now I have your full confidence let's move on!</div
        >
      </div>
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your messages span will have to have the `position: absolute` property...

```
<span class="message" style="width: 18.2105rem; height: 1.26316rem; opacity: 1; position:absolute;">Hello!  I hope you're having a good night</span>
```

Here's a working pen: https://codepen.io/paulmartin91/pen/RwpPaPL

Here's the explanation from [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp):

> By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be
> moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS
> position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!

Comment: Or `position: relative`, depending on what else you are trying to achieve